# Terraform - How to dynamically create resources

Tags: azure, terraform

I am learning how to work with terraform, which at the moment I am using to create Linux or windows VMs.

In my main.tf I am using some resources such as

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "this" {
  name                            = var.vm_name
  location                        = var.resources_location.name
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.this.id]
  size                            = var.vm_size
  admin_username                  = var.user
  admin_password                  = var.pass
  disable_password_authentication = false
  ...
}
```

From what I have read to create an Windows VM I must use:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]
}
```

The thing is, how need to create Linux machines and also Windows machines. So I was thinking I could use some logic and use `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` if I want to create a Linux VM or `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` if I want to create a windows VM.

Not sure if this is the most suitable way but can you point me in the right direction? And tell me how to implement some logic in main.tf so I can use my main.tf which is already working for Linux machines but reuse it for Windows VMs as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To conditionally created resources you can use [count](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count#when-to-use-for_each-instead-of-count). For example, you can have a new variable called "make_linux":

```
variable "make_linux" {
   default = true
}


resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "this" {
  count = var.make_linux == true ? 1 : 0
  # ...
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  count = var.make_linux == true ? 0 : 1
  # ...
}
```

This will create either windows or linux machine based on `var.make_linux`.

Comment: Hey, so will this be the better way to do this? Or is there a more suitable way? Like create another main.tf for example